# Bitwise And in R

Tags: python, r

I have the below function in Python which I need to convert into R

```
def hamming(h1, h2):
    h, d = 0, h1 ^ h2
    while d:
        h += 1
        d &= d - 1
    return h
```

But I don't know how to handle the bitwise piece.

**UPDATE:** 
I had to update the question since I did a mistake of not sharing what I had done.
I know about the BitWise operator but I was not getting the same answer. 
I should have included my code which would have not created all these confusion.

My apologies for not been precise with the question.

I had written the function as below:

```
hamming <- function(h1, h2) {
    h <- 0
    d <- h1^h2
    while (d) {
        h <- h + 1
        d = bitwAnd(d, d-1)
    }
    return(h)
}
```

But I seem to get different results from both the function. Don't know which line is wrong.

UPDATE: I took ^ in Python to be same in R and I was wrong. I figured out the issue.
Thanks everyone

Comment: Look up Python operators in the docs, and you will find your operator name. Then google the name of this operator with "r" appended to it. You will find what you're looking for :)

Comment: @DonkeyKong Thanks for your assistance. I updated the question but now I am struck with another issue.

Comment: _Please_ don't obfuscate your question by posting another question on top of it. Research the issue on your own, and if you are still stuck then perhaps you can come back to Stack Overflow and ask a __new__ question, although I would stress that Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of bitwise functions in base R. See `?bitwAnd` for the one you are looking for and others available.

Comment: Whilst I don't mind people down voting my answers it would be nice to know why this answer is inappropriate to avoid doing so again in future

Comment: Although I didn't downvote anything I'd guess some folks are missing "I tried ..., but it didn't work out because...". This would also address people like me who have little experience in Python but some in R. (I think currently you are addressing only those who know borth quite well.)

Comment: Thanks for responding @lukeA, although I am confused by your response, is this aimed at the question or the answer?

Comment: oops, I thought this was asked by the original poster. Blame it on the gin tonic - summer is finally here in Berlin. My bad..

Comment: @lukeA Ha no worries, enjoy the gin and tonic.

Comment: Although I also did not down vote, a more likely explanation is that some people don't appreciate it when low quality questions where the OP seemingly hasn't put in much effort quickly receive answers. They view it as reinforcing bad/rude behavior. In this case the OP clearly didn't bother even Googling "bitwise and in r", which would have returned precisely your answer.

Comment: Thank you @joran, that is at least logical.

Comment: OP being lazy is a nonsensical reason for downvoting a correct answer. At least I don't see that reason listed when I hover over the downvote button.

Comment: +1; I wasn't aware of these functions. Checking the NEWS, I see they were only added in version 3.0.0. I _had_ searched for such functions at times in the past, but obviously not recently. So thanks @jamieRowen

Comment: @jamieRowen Thanks for your response. I should have included what I had tried. That would have been good. I have updated the post with the details. Thank you